# Create singelton beans from enum

Tags: java, spring, configuration, autowired

I have an enum that looks like the following

```java
public enum MyBeanType {
  Type1,
  Type2
  ...
  Type100;
}
```

I would like to create a Bean for each of these enum values.

```java
public Class MyBean {
  private MyBeanType type;

 public MyBean(MyBeanType type) { this.type = type; }
}
```

I know I could list each of these in my config like so:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyBeanConfig() {

  @Bean public MyBean myBeanType1() { return new MyBean(MyBeanType.Type1);
  @Bean public MyBean myBeanType2() { return new MyBean(MyBeanType.Type2);
  ... 
  @Bean public MyBean myBeanType100() { return new MyBean(MyBeanType.Type100);  

}
```

But is there a way to do this more dynamically?
I'm typically wiring all of these in as a `List`, but there are some instances where I'd like to wire `myBeanType2` by name as well.

Comment: At first glance the immediate question is ***why do you want to do this?***.  I think this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  You should expand the question and explain what you're _really_ trying to accomplish using this questionable technique.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear... he wants a set of singleton beans each with a reference to an enum instance. Doesn't seem that far fetched to me and certainly not questionable.

Comment: I simplified my use case for this question.  I've got an events system that has several actions that can occur based on the source.  This enum is just 1 way I'm tracking some of the sources, but sources aren't limited to this enum either.  Not sure that really clears things up, but whether or not this is the right approach, I couldn't find anywhere on how to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) to play around with bean definitions.

```
@Bean
public BeanFactoryPostProcessor getBeanFactoryPostProcessor() {
  return beanFactory -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < MyBeanType.values().length; i++) {
      beanFactory.registerSingleton(MyBeanType.class.getSimpleName() + i, 
        new MyBean(MyBeanType.values()[i]));
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply register the beans programmatically. Something like this should do it.

```
@Configuration
public class MyBeanConfig() implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext ctx) {

        final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) ctx).getBeanFactory();

        for(final MyBeanType beanType: MyBeanType.values()) {

            beanFactory.registerSingleton(MyBean.class.getCanonicalName() + "_" + beanType, new MyBean(beanType));
        }
    }
}
```